# Best setting of MadiaDB database Server (version: 10.1.29-MariaDB) for data about 400GB

Tags: configuration, mariadb-10.1

I have a single server with 128GB and 64 core CPU.
I need to compare multiple tables (about 40 tables) having ~400GB data.
The maximum size of a table has ~60GB data for upload as CSV file.
With the given setting, how can I get the maximum performance for upload CSV and compare tables fields which are mostly numbers?